# value injector for cloning one class to another object type

Tags: .net, vb.net, mapper, valueinjecter

I am using this however, I do not see any values of properties being cloned/injected from the source to the target object.

I know I am not correctly doing it, could someone please help me?

```
Protected Overrides Function SetValue(c As ConventionInfo) As Object
        If c.SourceProp.Type.IsValueType OrElse c.SourceProp.Type = GetType(String) OrElse c.TargetProp.Type.IsValueType OrElse c.TargetProp.Type = GetType(String) Then
            Return c.SourceProp.Value
        End If

        If c.SourceProp.Type.IsClass Then
            Dim obj = TryCast(c.SourceProp.Value, Object)
            If obj IsNot Nothing Then
                Dim clone = TryCast(Activator.CreateInstance(c.TargetProp.Type), Object)


                Return clone
            End If
        End If

        Return Activator.CreateInstance(c.TargetProp.Type).InjectFrom(Of CloneInjection)(c.SourceProp.Value)
```